# Traverse through Javascript object properties

Tags: javascript

I want to traverse through JavaScript object's property

```
var obj =
{
    a: 'value1',
    b: 'value2',
    c: 'value3',
    d: 'value4'
};

for (var prop in obj) {
    prop = 'xxx';
}
```

But the above code is not working. Can you help me how to do so ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`prop` will reference the property name, not its value.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    obj[prop] = 'xxx';
}
```

[Construct documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For...in)

Also you may want to check if the property belongs to the object using `hasOwnProperty`. It may happen that someone adds properties to the prototype and those are also iterated by `for ... in`.

Answer (score 96):

You should check that the property belongs to the object and not a prototype.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        obj[prop] = 'xxx';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would I still want to check "hasOwnProperty"? What can go wrong with "prop in obj"?

Comment: Because it will also return _inherited_ properties from the prototype chain. Hence you need to check if the property is from the current object. You can read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only

Comment: It has no inherited properties

Answer (score 28):

Here is how it is done using the ES5 - Object.keys() :

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, idx) {
   ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magiccrafter/bvwenh5d/

Mozilla's docs: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I prefer this approach because it only iterates through an objects "own" properties...e.g. no need for the `hasOwnProperty` conditional.  Hooray for modern JS!

Comment: Some ES6 arrow function to avoid "this" problems Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, idx) => {
   ...
});

Answer (score 7):

Using ecmascript2017:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(let i = 0; i < Object.entries(dog).length; i++){
  this.temp.push(Object.entries(dog)[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj = {
"abc":1, "def":2
}
for (let key in obj){
  console.log(key+":"+obj[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you're in an ES6 friendly environment, you can also try using the for...of loop which is closer to your original attempt.</strike>

EDIT: As Caleb pointed out, `for..of` is specific to collections with the Symbol.iterator property (e.g. not standard JS objects).

But I'm leaving this answer here in case anybody else finds it useful at some point to have it pointed out explicitly that a `for..of` is not a great solution here.

```
let obj = {};

for (let prop of obj) { // This will throw an error
    prop = 'xxx';
}
```

Reference: [MDN - for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: I think needs a little tweaking since `obj` is not an array. Also better to use `let` if you have an ES6 environment. `for (let prop of Object.keys(obj)) { obj[prop] = 'xxx'; }`

Comment: @Caleb The point of the 'for...of' loop is to iterate over an object, not an array. If you're going to fetch the keys, then you may as well just use a standard for loop but you're also making the code unnecessarily complex. +1 on using 'let' tho

Comment: I tried it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fvqkIMVeuL) to double check but the `for ... of` can't iterate through an object. It responds with a `Uncaught TypeError: obj[Symbol.iterator] is not a function` error. But yeah it doesn't make it seem very useful if you have to write it what I have above in my comment...

Comment: @Caleb Yep, my mistake. `for...of` doesn't support standard js objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
var temp= {"6s","vikash","500"};
console.log([...temp]); //["6s","vikash","500"]
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.